# How to refresh the client in Tornado?

Tags: http, refresh, tornado

After the client press a button（method = "post"）,I would do something in the database,then refresh the client's current page.How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Project tree:

```
$ tree
.
├── static
│   └── scripts
│       └── test.js
├── templates
│   └── index.html
└── test.py
```

Tornado code:

```py
# test.py
import os
import logging
import time

import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen

from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html", data=self.data["status"])
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine
    def post(self):
        action = self.get_argument('action')
        if action == 'reload':
            logging.info('background job start')
            yield tornado.gen.Task(tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 3)
            logging.info('background job stop')
            self.data["status"] = "reloaded"
            self.finish("{}")

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {"status":"initialized"}
        handlers = [
            (r"/", IndexHandler, {"data":self.data}),
        ]
        settings = dict(
            static_path = 'static',
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
        )
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = Application()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Template page:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript reload example</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ static_url('scripts/test.js') }}" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="reload" id="reload-button" /><br/>
    {{data}}
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file:

```js
/* test.js */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reload-button').click(function(event) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '//localhost:8888/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'reload',
            },          
            success: function() {
                window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm yielding `add_timeout` to simulate database operation.